# R: sum positive values and sum negative values

Tags: r, vector, sum

I've got a vector:

```
vec <- c(1,-2,9,-7,7,4,5,2,1,-10)
```

Now I would like to take the sum of the negative values in vec, and the sum of the positive values in vec.

```
neg <- sum of the negative values in vec
pos <- sum of the positive values in vec
```

Comment: Or you could save the result in a list using something like `lapply(split(vec, vec > 0), sum)`

Comment: Or split using `sign` to have slightly more meaningful names for your list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
neg <- sum(vec[vec<0]);
pos <- sum(vec[vec>0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pos <- sum(subset(vec, vec > 0))
neg <- sum(subset(vec, vec < 0))
```

Or:

```
l <- split(vec, vec < 0)
pos <- sum(l[[1]])
neg <- sum(l[[2]])
```

Or as mentioned by @David in the comments:

```
m <- lapply(split(vec, vec < 0), sum)
pos <- m[[1]]
neg <- m[[2]]
```